# Is there a way to make isotope fill all the white space for a fixed width div

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Is there a way to make isotope fill all the white spaces on a row?

The container has a fixed width and 3 different types of boxes (3 widths and a fixed height). I see 3 possible solutions:

1. Make isotope look further down the list and make the decision in what is the best way to combine the boxes so there are fewer white spaces and those spaces are all at the bottom of the container. In this case we need enough boxes of different sizes.
2. Resize some of the boxes and move them so the row is always full.
3. Detect the number of boxes and their sizes before they are placed in the container and change the size for some of them, so there is a variety of sizes and hopefully isotope will have less rows with white spaces.

I hope someone can put me in the right direction

Answer (score 5):

In short, Isotope does not have these features. But if you're a talented developer, you could add them yourself

1. This feature has been requested, however I have no plans to  implement such a feature. See: https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/125
2. Resizing items is outside the scope of Isotope. Isotope only positions items
3. See 2

[Isotope is extendible.](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/extending-isotope.html) While I have no intention to add these features, you could create your own custom layout mode that does it.